# How to Download Gmail Credentials.json File from google cloud using C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Good day!

I have already developed an email sending application using C#. First of all, I have to create the credentials.json file manually and then set the location. Now, I would like to know how to download the credentials.json file from my application without any interaction by using my Gmail credentials and then setting the location.
Thanks in advance.

I have use this code.

```
        string credPath = "path_to_credentials.json";

       
        var credentialParameters = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        };
        
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(credPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                credentialParameters,
                scopes,
                "user",
                System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath)).Result;
        }
```

But I would like to download credentials.json file and send email.

Comment: Why? Even if you could, it doesn't seem safe transporting that data through email.

Comment: Thanks. I have to create a new credential and set it daily before sending an email. That's why I want to download automatically when my Gmail credentials expire.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you understand the propose of the credentials.json file.  Lets open the file and have a look.

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "[REDACTED]",
    "project_id": "daimto-tutorials-101",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "[REDACTED]",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

The two key points in this file are the client_id and which identifies your application to google. and the client_secret which is like a password for the client id and used to sign the tokens.

This file does not expire and will not stop working unless you delete it from Google cloud console.

## Your questions

> I have to create the credentials.json file manually and then set the location.

This is exactly how you should have done this.

> Now, I would like to know how to download the credentials.json file from my application without any interaction by using my Gmail credentials and then setting the location.

There is no way to programmatically request a new credentials.json.  A credentials.json file is created by the developer for their applicaiton. One application one credentials.json for development and one credentials.json for production.

> I have to create a new credential and set it daily before sending an email. That's why I want to download automatically when my Gmail credentials expire.

You do not have to set a new credentials.json before using it.  It does not expire.

## Correction.

What is expiring is probably your access token or maybe the refresh token if your app is still in testing but only after seven days.

You are using `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` which contains `filedatastore` which is storing the users tokens in %appdata% on your machine. The library will refresh your access token when ever is needed.